# Icons label of Unity launcher sometimes disappear

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher, icons

From a while the icons label of Unity disappear sometimes. If I'm not wrong this issue started with the latest update of Unity (I have unity 5.14.0). I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.1.
Any idea to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug which is fixed for the next Unity update (5.16). See the complete bugreport: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1034164